# Angular Events from different components

Tags: php, angular, typescript, session, service

I am trying to make my session variables be destroyed on logout. Calling of php scrips is happening in my api.service.ts script. The page that this is happening on is being run from app.component.html.

```
<button type="button" *ngIf="logoutbtn" class="btn btn-block" (click)="logout()">logout</button>
```

is calling the logout() function from my app.component.ts script.

```
logout()
{
    this.dataService.deleteToken();
    // Close session here
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

The api.service.ts file has my code for calling the php script:

```
logoutUser(){
  return this.httpClient.get<Policy[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/logout.php`, { withCredentials: true });
}
```

How can I communicate from my app.component.ts and call on that line of code "close session here" to call the function from my api.service.ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dependency injection,

1. import `api.service.ts` file in `app.component.ts`
2. declare it in constructor
3. use it like the way use have used `deleteToken()` method
4. EX - inside the logout function

   ```
   this.apiService.logoutUser().subscribe( response = > {

      console.log("user logged out with api call");

   })
   ```

Comment: I added 

`constructor(private dataService: ApiService)`

then I run `this.dataService.logoutUser();` but I don't see the php script being called on the other end. I have an error_log running in the server to see if it is being called at all. Is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: @ConnorThomas you got it working right? this is the proper way.